# How do I change the background color using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change the background color to a color randomly selected form an array, but I'm not sure what I'm doing. I'm mostly confused about how to make the button work.

This is the body of the HTML, eventually I will have to change the text to the name of the color that it changes to, but I want to get the color first:

```js
const colors = ['#e5051b', '#f6e06a', '#f1a432', '#a9b724', '#458a92', '#aa0c90', '#301196d', '#f2b8a2', 'fdbb2f', '27d193'];

const randomColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];

let button = document.getElementById('button');

button.addEventListener('click', function changeColor() {
    
    const color = randomColor;
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = `${color}`;
});
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="box">
        <div>
            <p>Hex color code: #ffffff</p>
            <button class="button">Change Color</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: first of all change `class="button"` to `id="button"` as you are getting the element reference with its `id` in your js

Comment: Then change to a function: `const randomColor = () => colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];` calli it `document.body.style.backgroundColor = randomColor()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things that you are doing wrong here. 
First one is, getting element by id that does not exist in the `DOM`. You must be get an error in your console because of that. 
Secondly, you are just picking a random color when the script runs and not everytime when the button is clicked.

So what you should be doing is, either change the `class="button"` to `id="button"` or change `getElementById` to `getElementsByClassName[0]`. 
To get random color on every click, you should move the logic inside your click handler to run it each time and pick a random color from the give array of colors.

```js
const colors = ['#e5051b', '#f6e06a', '#f1a432', '#a9b724', '#458a92', '#aa0c90', '#301196d', '#f2b8a2', 'fdbb2f', '27d193'];

const randomColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];

let button = document.getElementById('button');
let p = document.getElementById('color');

button.addEventListener('click', function changeColor() {
    const randomColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
    const color = randomColor;
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = `${color}`;
    p.textContent = `Hex color is ${color}`
});
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="box">
        <div>
            <p id="color">Hex color is #ffff</p>
            <button id="button">Change Color</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: or `document.querySelector(".button")` or delegate in case of more buttons

Comment: yeah that makes more sense :)

Comment: They are equally compatible, actually querySelector is a little more compatible than getElementsByClassName (not that it matters in 2020)

Comment: yeah they can be used interchangeably. I personally vote for `querySelector` as it is easy for me to differentiate when using `querySelectorAll`. you know selecting one or more than one type of scenarios

Answer (score 0):

you have to random color every click

```js
const colors = ['#e5051b', '#f6e06a', '#f1a432', '#a9b724', '#458a92', '#aa0c90', '#301196d', '#f2b8a2', 'fdbb2f', '27d193'];

let button = document.getElementById('button');

button.addEventListener('click', function changeColor() {
  let randomColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = `${randomColor}`;
});
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="box">
    <div>
      <p>Hex color code: #ffffff</p>
      <button id="button">Change Color</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you are trying to get the ref to the button by id where you have used class in your button
2. getElementsByClassName return an array you need to select the first one
3. color will only get generated once and stored in colors. if you want to get random color every time you need to generate it on click

here's the correct code

```js
const colors = ['#e5051b','#f6e06a', '#f1a432', '#a9b724', '#458a92', '#aa0c90', '#301196d', '#f2b8a2', 'fdbb2f', '27d193'];


let button = document.getElementsByClassName('button');
console.log(button);
button[0].addEventListener('click',function changeColor() 
{
    const color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];

    console.log(color)
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = `${color}`;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all as mentioned in the comment you are using wrong element selector.

```
 let button = document.querySelector('.button');
```

After that, you should put randomization code within the click event listener, so that random color will be generated each time the button is clicked

```
button.addEventListener('click',function changeColor() 
{
   let random_color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
   document.body.style.backgroundColor = `${color}`;
});
```